# Understanding the relative interior of a set

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set. I work with the following definition of the relative interior
\begin{equation}
\text{relint}(S):=\{s\in S\,\,|\,\,\exists\,\delta>0: B(s,\delta)\cap \text{aff}(S) \subset S\}.
\end{equation}

My questions:

1. Am I correct that this is nothing else than the interior of $S$ with respect to the subspace topology on $\text{aff}(S)$? I do not immediately see from the above definition why this is the case, but it seems to me like this is true.
2. Is it correct that we have $\text{relint}(S)\neq \text{int}(S)\cap\text{aff}(S)$? I thought that we could choose $S$ to be a closed segment, where $\text{int}(S)$ is empty and $\text{relint}(S)$ equals the open segment.
3. Is it true that we always have $\text{int}(S) \subset \text{relint}(S)$? I think this holds as $B(s,\delta)\subset S$ immediately implies $B(s,\delta)\cap\text{aff}(S)\subset S$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $\text{aff}(S)$? I've never seen that notation used.

Comment: It's the affine hull of $S$.

Comment: Could you define it in the question? I feel that it's not a super standard object.

Comment: You’re correct on all three counts.

Comment: @Jose27 An affine subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (also called an “affine manifold”) is what you get if you take a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and shift it away from the origin. The affine hull of a set $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ is the smallest affine set containing $S$. In other words, it’s the intersection of all the affine sets which contain $S$. The affine hull of $\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2 + y^2 =1, z=1\}$ is the plane $z = 1$, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes this is true: from the definition of subspace topology interior, if $x \in \text{int}_{\text{aff}(C)}( C)$ then there exists a set of the form $U \cap \text{aff}(C)$ contained in $C$ that contains $x$ for some $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Then choosing an open ball $B$ containing $x$ and contained in $U$, we obtain $x \in B\cap \text{aff}(C) \subseteq C$ so $x \in \text{ri}(C)$. See if you can prove the other inclusion yourself.
2. In general this is false, as you said. Take $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The relative interior is $(0,1)$ while the interior is empty, and the affine hull is the $x$-axis.
3. True, for the reasons you stated.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me where I can find the definition of the subspace topology interior?

Comment: @physicist23 Subspace topology interior is just interior but your sets must be open in the subspace topology. So if $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ and we give $B$ the subspace topology, then $\text{int}_B(A)$ is the set of $x$ for which there exists an open set $O$ (in the $B$ subspace topology) containing $x$ and contained in $A$. Every such $O$ is of the form $U \cap B$ for $U$ open in the $C$ topology. Here is a link to a proper discussion of subspaces: http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/notes/07-subspaces.pdf

Comment: I see! For an arbitrary topological space $(X, \mathcal{O})$ and a subset $A\subset X$, the interior of $A$ is defined by $\text{int}_X(A):=\{x\in A\,|\, \exists\, O\in\mathcal{O}: x\in O\subset A\}$. And here we choose the topological space as $\text{aff}(S)$ with the subspace topology. I guess the remaining inclusion $\text{relint}(S) \subset \text{int}_{\text{aff}(S)}(S)$ is then clear as we find a $\delta >0$ with $x\in B(x,\delta)\cap\text{aff}(S)\subset S$ and the set $B(x,\delta)\cap\text{aff}(S)$ is open in $\text{aff}(S)$ by definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: @physicist23 precisely!